# Can you help? Computer shut down and brightness level changed by itself

Tags: system, syslog

My computers screen brightness changed and then a few hours later it shut down by itself. I looked into system log and I found this for screen brightness:

```
Mar 26 09:17:01 My-PC CRON[12162]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root

Mar 26 09:51:10 My-PC pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)

Mar 26 09:51:10 My-PC pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session

**Mar 26 09:51:10 My-PC pkexec[12500]: computer: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/computer] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/usd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 158]**

Mar 26 10:17:01 My-PC CRON[12756]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Mar 26 10:17:01 My-PC CRON[12756]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

*I searched for pkexec[12500] and I found out that pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user.. What does this mean? Could this command be used by a hacker?*

As for shutting down I found this is sys.log around the time it shut down:

```
Mar 26 12:17:01 My-PC CRON[13894]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

Mar 26 12:57:22 My-PC kernel: [71651.239315] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=anbox0 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c8a0:59ff:feaa:bfbf DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:00fb LEN=166 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=510582 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=126 

Mar 26 12:57:22 My-PC kernel: [71651.239446] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=anbox0 SRC=192.168.250.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=146 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=13205 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=126 

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Firmware update daemon...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Session c2 of user computer.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Stopped target Default.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Stopped target Basic System.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Stopped target Timers.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Stopped target Sockets.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC pulseaudio[2351]: [pulseaudio] module-x11-publish.c: PulseAudio information vanished from X11!

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Stopped target Paths.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Reached target Shutdown.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[2008]: Starting Exit the Session...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC bluetoothd[1234]: Terminating

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Service for snap application anbox.container-manager...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC bluetoothd[1234]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping crash report submission daemon...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC bluetoothd[1234]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...

Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1252" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

*Can you explain what these messages mean:*

```
Mar 26 12:17:01 My-PC CRON[13894]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

Mar 26 12:57:22 My-PC kernel: [71651.239315] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=anbox0 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c8a0:59ff:feaa:bfbf DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:00fb LEN=166 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=510582 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=126
```

Is this about anbox? I installed it using a guide online. Why would it be trying to communicate online? How do I stop it from starting by itself?

In auth.log I found this:

```
Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC systemd-logind[1265]: System is powering down.
```

Can you tell what this means?

```
**Mar 26 13:00:14 My-PC polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.75, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)**
```

Comment: Hi! your question needs some formatting. you made text that you wrote formatted as code and text from the logs formatted as text you wrote. We want logs to be formated as code and what you're trying to tell us to **not** be formated as code. Select paragraphs and use the `{}` symbol in the editor to toggle between code and non-code format. when there are four or more spaces before the begining of a newline this will show up as code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I just copied what I found in sys.log and auth.log . I have added the spaces myself for it to become easier to read.

Comment: read your post. can you find what you wrote vs logs? pretty hard right? for example where is "I searched for pkexec[12500] and I found out that pkexec allows"? this is text you wrote and yet it is formatted as logs... and vice-versa. I'm asking you to reverse this. please.

Comment: I edited the question. Is it okay now?

Comment: no. you are still doing the opposite. you are still applying style to your statements instead of applying style to the logs. also the style should be "code" not "quote". let me do it...

Comment: ok I did the edits. you don't need to touch it.

Comment: Can you answer the question?

Comment: how about reinstalling ubuntu? if your system is acting up you could do that. start again with a clean base. I'm no expert on brightness changing by itself. but I doubt you can reproduce with a fresh install with no programs interfering.